# Crystal Reports: Passing Parameters via winform VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I am currently using crystal reports XI and VB studio 2005. I'm facing problem  passing parameter to the report via the winform. Below is my code:

In my report form where the crystal control resides:

```
Public Sub DisplayReport(ByVal formTitle As String)
Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
myConnectionInfo.UserID = ""
myConnectionInfo.Password = ""

SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo, rptDoc) 

Me.Text = formTitle

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc 
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub

Private Sub SetDBLogonForReport(ByVal myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo, ByVal myReportDocument As ReportDocument)
    Dim myTables As Tables = myReportDocument.Database.Tables
    For Each myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In myTables
        Dim myTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
        myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
        myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo)
    Next
End Sub
```

In my printing report form where I call the report form:

```
Private Sub ConfigureCrystalReport(ByVal btnPrint As Boolean)
    Dim myRptView As New frmReportView
    Dim rptFile As String = ""
    Dim strSelFormula As String = ""

    'getting report path dynamically
    Dim rptPath1 As New getAppDBSettingsBLL
    rptPath1 = New getAppDBSettingsBLL
    Dim rptPath As String = rptPath1.getReportPath(4)
    rptFile = rptPath & "\" & "XXX.rpt" 

    myRptView = New frmReportView
    rptDoc.Load(rptFile)


    myRptView.DisplayReport(Me.Text)

    rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@dateA", Format(Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, "mm/dd/yyyy"))

    myRptView.Show()

    myRptView.CrystalReportViewer1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    myRptView.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

End Sub
```

I am pulling data from a join SQL statement based on the parameter, to be used in the report. SQL statement is correct and value passed is correct. But the parameter prompt box keeps coming up, I want to suppress it. When enter the parameter in the prompt box, the report showed correctly. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This type of parameter `"@dateA"` is for `Stored Procedure`

and this type of Parameter `"dateA"` is for a normal calling from `Crystal Parameter` itself

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're making a CR parameter, the parameter should start with "?", not "@".

Second, for the parameter box keep popping up, what you can do is on the page load of your crystal report viewer form, paste this:

```
Dim param1Fields As New ParameterFields
Dim param1Field As New ParameterField
Dim param1Range As New ParameterDiscreteValue

param1Field.ParameterFieldName = "Write your parameter name"
param1Range.Value = <provide your parameter value>
param1Field.CurrentValues.Add(param1Range)
param1Fields.Add(param1Field)
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = param1Fields
```